# How to structure a .NET Core MVC project for multiple user roles?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

Assuming you had multiple user roles (such as Customer, Employee, Manager) and wanted to provide a personalised experience (different home page, different pages accessable by different roles), what would be the best way to set this up to make it scalable?

Currently we are considering using areas for the different roles.

E.G. A manager would be directed to the manager area home page when logging in whereas a customer would be directed to the customer area home page.

Is there a better way to structure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally we redirect user to different pages via navigation menu/bar in web site, if you'd like to show different pages based on user's role, you can dynamically render/display navigation menu/bar by checking current user's role after user signed into site.

```
@if (!SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm navbar-light bg-white border-bottom box-shadow mb-3">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">WebApp</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                    <partial name="_LoginPartial" />
                    <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
}
else
{
    if (User.IsInRole("manager"))
    {
        //navigation bar for manager

        //html content here
        //...

        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="Manager" asp-controller="controller_name_here" asp-action="action_name_here">Admin Home</a>
    }
    else if (User.IsInRole("employee"))
    {
        //navigation bar for employee
    }
    else
    {
        //navigation bar for employee
    }
```

> Currently we are considering using areas for the different roles.

[Areas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-3.1) provide a way to partition an ASP.NET Core Web app into smaller functional groups. Under the scenario you mentioned, grouping functionality within Customer, Employee and Manager units, which would make project structure more clear.